# Printing all keys and values in a JSON in a CSV format

Tags: linux, bash, csv, jq, paste

I have several large JSON files that I need to rewrite into a single file but I am only able to do it in a nasty way that writes a lot of temporary files. Let's look at a simplified version of my problem, `example.json`:

```
{
  "a": {
    "number": 1,
    "word": "foo"
  },
  "b": {
    "number": 2,
    "word": "bar"
  },
  "c": {
    "number": 3,
    "word": "zebra"
  }
}
```

I want to obtain:

```
a,1,foo
b,2,bar
c,3,zebra
```

My solution:

```
jq 'keys | .[]' example.json | tr -d '"' > file1.csv
jq '.[] | .number' example.json > file2.csv
jq '.[] | .word' example.json | tr -d '"' > file3.csv

paste -d',' file1.csv file2.csv > file4.csv
paste -d',' file4.csv file3.csv > file5.csv
```

In the code above I know I could have simplified it more by writing `jq -r '.[] | [.number, .word] | @csv'` instead of `jq '.[] | .word'` thus avoiding half of the mess but let's keep it this way because my question is related to the plumbing part.

I have tried many ways of redirecting the output of `jq` into `paste` but I never succeed:

```
paste <$(jq 'keys | .[]' example.json | tr -d '"') file2.csv
paste $(jq 'keys | .[]' example.json | tr -d '"') file2.csv
jq 'keys | .[]' example.json | tr -d '"') | paste file2.csv
```

How do I put the output of `jq` into `paste` without having to create intermediate files?

Comment: Were you looking for process substitution, `<(...)` (instead of `<$(...)`)?

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, thanks, seems like `paste -d',' <(jq 'keys | .[]' example.json | tr -d '"') <(paste -d','  <(jq '.[] | .number' example.json) <(jq '.[] | .word' example.json | tr -d '"'))` does the job

Comment: How do I know when I should use process substitution or when I should use piping or other things like $()?

Comment: Process substitution for when you want to treat the output of a command like a file, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash, you can use [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
paste -d, <(jq ...) <(jq ...) <(jq ...)
```

Note that paste accepts multiple files, not only two.

Comment: How do I know when I should use process substitution or when I should use piping or other things like $()?

Comment: In place of command substitution, $(cmd), you’ll have the output of the cmd. In place of process substitution, <(cmd), you’ll get temporary filename in which the output of cmd will go. Paste then just reads from that temp file. Try running “echo” with both to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Why would need `paste` and other bunch of shell utils, when you can do it all it in `jq`

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key),\(.value | .number),\(.value | .word)"' json
```

Comment: `jq` is documented at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/, but the manual isn't the best place for examples of idiomatic use. I've had more luck with Stack Overflow!

Comment: `jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key),\(.value | "\(.number),\(.word)")"' inp.json` is ok too, string interpolation is a great feature

Comment: Better to use the `@csv` filter instead of rolling it out manually.